# Find value in table Excel without column information

Tags: excel

Ive got a problem which I think is not super difficult to solve. However, Im failing to solve it tough Im desperate to find the solution.

The situation:

```
+---+----+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|   | A  |     B     |    C     |     D     |    E     |     F     |    G     |     H     |    I     |
+---+----+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| 1 | ID | Firstname | Lastname | Firstname | Lastname | Firstname | Lastname | Firstname | Lastname |
| 2 | A. | Mia       | Smith    | David     | Miller   | Logan     | Jackson  |           |          |
| 3 | B. | Avery     | Johnson  | Elizabeth | Davis    | Oliver    | Thomas   | Joseph    | Lee      |
| 4 | C. | Chloe     | Williams | Sofia     | garcia   |           |          |           |          |
| 5 | D. | Daniel    | Brown    | Ella      | Wilson   | David     | Sanchez  |           |          |
| 6 | E. | Lucas     | Jones    |           |          |           |          |           |          |
+---+----+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

What I want is to look up, using a formula, the last names of David; which are Miller and Sanchez, they appear in the cell on the right of David. Like when I type David in cell A8, Miller appears in cell A9 and Sanchez appears in A10. Above the information is given which is present in the file.

Comment: How about Ctrl+F? Or do you mean like lookup with a formula or a macro? And what do you mean by "lookup" - get the row and column? And what do you mean by "no information is present about the columns"? I noticed there are columns Firstname followed by Lastname - is this a rule we can rely on or just a coincidence? This is very poorly stated problem.

Comment: You can use this formula to find how many times "david" appears in the columns.  =SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"B:B","D:D","F:F","H:H"}),"David")) Like V.K. I'm confused as to what exactly you are trying to accomplish, but this may be helpful.

Comment: True that, Im sorry I wasnt clear. I edited the post so hopefully it is better defined now.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do now.  Are you familiar with VBA? Or do you want this to have a pure formula solution?

Comment: I prefer a pure formula solution. However, when it is too complicated VBA would also be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

enter the following User Defined Function in a standard module:

```
Public Function GetSurname(rng As Range, fName As String) As Variant
    Dim r As Range, ary(), K As Long
    K = 0
    ReDim ary(1)
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value = fName Then
            If K = 0 Then
                ary(0) = r.Offset(0, 1).Value
                K = K + 1
            Else
                ReDim Preserve ary(K)
                ary(K) = r.Offset(0, 1).Value
                K = K + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    GetSurname = ary
End Function
```

Pick a cell, say **C10** and enter the given name.  Then select the adjacent cells, from **D10** onwards and enter the array formula:

```
=getsurname(B2:I6,C10)
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image]

The **#N/A**'s can be suppressed afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is probably easier to solve this problem with VBA.  I'm sure there is a way to do what you want with all formulas, but I think it is going beyond the reasonable scope of formulas given the multiple repetative columns.

Here is what I created:

```
Sub test()

first_nm = Worksheets(1).Range("K2").Value
col1_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B"))
col2_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("D:D"))
col3_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("F:F"))
col4_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("H:H"))

Worksheets(1).Range("L2:L500").ClearContents

y = 2
x = 2
Do While x <= col1_row
    If Cells(y, 2) = first_nm Then
      If Cells(2, 12) = "" Then
         Cells(2, 12) = Cells(y, 3).Value
      Else: Range("L1").End(xlDown).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = Cells(y, 3).Value
      End If
    End If

    If Cells(y, 2) <> "" Then
       x = x + 1
    End If
y = y + 1
Loop

y = 2
x = 2
Do While x <= col2_row
    If Cells(y, 4) = first_nm Then
      If Cells(2, 12) = "" Then
         Cells(2, 12) = Cells(y, 5).Value
      Else: Range("L1").End(xlDown).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = Cells(y, 5).Value
      End If
    End If

    If Cells(y, 4) <> "" Then
       x = x + 1
    End If
y = y + 1
Loop


y = 2
x = 2
Do While x <= col3_row
    If Cells(y, 6) = first_nm Then
      If Cells(2, 12) = "" Then
         Cells(2, 12) = Cells(y, 7).Value
      Else: Range("L1").End(xlDown).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = Cells(y, 7).Value
      End If
    End If

    If Cells(y, 6) <> "" Then
       x = x + 1
    End If
y = y + 1
Loop


y = 2
x = 2
Do While x <= col4_row
    If Cells(y, 8) = first_nm Then
      If Cells(2, 12) = "" Then
         Cells(2, 12) = Cells(y, 9).Value
      Else: Range("L1").End(xlDown).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = Cells(y, 9).Value
      End If
    End If

    If Cells(y, 8) <> "" Then
       x = x + 1
    End If
y = y + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

I'll be the first to admit this could be done more efficiently by looping through the columns, but I felt like since there were only four columns it would be simpler to write like this.

In order for this to work, all you have to do is put the first name you would like to look up, in your case "David" (it is case sensitive) in cell K2 of the same worksheet and then run the macro.  It will populate the last names in descending order starting in cells L2.  Of course you can change where the input and output values go if you want.

If you want it to run without having to manually press a button or run it through the developer tab, you can have a change in cell K2 call the macro.